# The fastest way to list thousands of folders in local drive in PHP On windows OS?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the way I list my folder's folders [ only folder ]:

```
foreach(glob('k:\\thousandoffolders\\*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $folders){
    echo basename($folders).' '; // get folder's name
}
```

So,is it the right way!?

And my purpose is to get `all folder's name` which inside special folder and store them in the database `MySQL`.E.g:

```
drives with special folders:

D:\folderContainer
E:\folderContainer
...
H:\folderContainer
```

and every `folderContainer` may be contain `thousands of folders`.And I just want to go through all the `folderContainers` and get all folders' name then store inside `MySQL`.And if folder's name exist in database the `MySQL` could return it to notice and continue store next one.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why [`scandir`](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) is not used? Regular expressions that `glob()` uses are not very efficient. I'd go with:

```
foreach(scandir('k:\\thousandoffolders\\') as $folder){
    if (in_array($folder, array('.', '..'))) continue;
    echo basename($folder).' '; // get folder's name
}
```

---

**Update**

In response to comments, I ran a test to see what the actual performance gains are.

According to results it took over 1.5 seconds for `glob()` to burn through 10 000 directories while `scandir()` completed the same task in 0.2 seconds. That is **700%** faster.

Comment: No.I am new to PHP,and I just find out glob used a lots in google search! Yeah.The scandir run much faster!

Comment: Considering that the operation will have tons of disk IO, I don't think regular expressions or anything else will come close to having a noticeable performance difference.

Comment: @Jon: That's still no excuse to use an inferior mechanism for no reason. At best it's bad habit; at worst you're hogging CPU cycles from other processes, regardless of whether or not you're waiting on I/O.

Comment: @Tomalak: Agreed. Saul's answer is definitely better than the OP's code. It's just that I wouldn't expect it to be significantly faster in wall clock time.

Comment: @Jon: Nor I. Though with the indicated quantity of input folders, you never know!

Comment: @Jon: I ran a test to read 10000 directories: `scandir()` completed in 0.2 seconds but `glob()` took 1.5 seconds. I'd say it's quite a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using exec and dir to write to a textfile.

```
exec('dir D:\folderContainer /ad >tempfile.txt')
```

That will be really fast, you can subsequently use MySQLs `LOAD DATA` with the replace parameter to insert your data in the MySQL table, or work on that file with PHP